# Are there any libraries for Python to simulate keyboard action?

Tags: python, windows, keyboard

The problem I have is that I have this Python script to launch a application. After the application is launched (the GUI is shown on screen), I want to make it de-activated. It can be done manually by activating another window, or minimizing this app, or pressing the Show Desktop key for WindowsXP.

So is there any way that I can do this by Python? Core or 3rd party library would be all ok.

Thanks!

Comment: Between your three techniques for de-activating, I'd recommend minimization, as it will have the fewest side-effects.  The keyboard command for minimization is Alt-Space (to open the system menu), then N (to select Minimize).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [SendKeys](http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/). It is in the [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/SendKeys/0.3), so you can install it via `easy_install`.

Comment: SendKeys is a very thin wrapper around the W32 SendKeys interface so there is plenty of documentation out there - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx is a good page if you want to send any special keycodes

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) to [send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx) a [minimize event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632646(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I've used AutoIt (via it's COM interface) a lot of times