# Simulate mouse/keyboard events (gtk + HOOPS 3D)

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gdk, hoops

how can I simulate mouse/keyboard events in gtk/gdk? I have a window widget containing HOOPS 3D widget and need to simulate mouse clicking on various parts of the window, along with simulating keyboard, ie. CTRL pressed, etc.

I found http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-Testing.html but this isn't quite what I need (specific X,Y, and keyboard events)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I need this to invoke HOOPS 3D widget's events, I found that it is not necessary to do it through gtk, it is possible to do so by injecting events into hoops itself http://developer.hoops3d.com/documentation/HoopsMVO/ref_manual/class_h_event_info.html - Using the SetWindowPos API.

Answer (score 1):

override function from base class HBaseOperator.  create a new operator class.
ex: public class xx: HBaseOperator
{

}

Answer (score 0):

will this help at all: [Are there any libraries for Python to simulate keyboard action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767575/are-there-any-libraries-for-python-to-simulate-keyboard-action)    ::::::   http://pypi.python.org/pypi/SendKeys/0.3

Comment: No, I need this for all platforms, not just windows. Thanks though! May come in handy someday. I found the solution though.